# Alter UIView elements outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an EventsManager class that communicates with my view controller. I would like to be able to update `UIView` elements (images, progress bar, etc) by calling methods inside my view (like updateProgressBar, for example) from the EventManager class.

However, anytime I try to update `UIView` elements from within any method in my view other than `viewDidLoad`, it's just ignored entirely.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Super simple example:

This works

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  progressBar.progress = 0.5;
}
```

This does not (this method is in my view controller)

```
- (void)updateProgressBar:(float)myProgress
{
  NSLog(@"updateProgressBar called.");
  progressBar.progress = myProgress;
}
```

So, if I call:

```
float currentProgress = 1.0;

ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewController updateProgressBar:currentProgress]
```

from my EventsManager class, `updateProgressBar` *is* called (proven with breakpoints), but the progress bar update is ignored. No errors or exceptions thrown. and `updateProgressBar called.` is displayed in the console.

Comment: Can you provide code snippets elucidating the issue? Difficult to answer such a generic scenario. In principle, you should be able to update your view from places other than viewDidLoad, but everything depends on your design. Please provide more clarity.

Comment: Added example. It's pretty basic. My design is not complex or original. It's a basic view with a couple of UIView elements.

Comment: The code looks ok at a quick glance..I hope this is not the exact code you have- since in both the cases, your progressBar.progress is at 0.7 which means even if updateProgressBar gets executed, the progressBar won't show any progress. Can you please confirm that this is not the case?

Comment: No, that is not the case. I was trying to make my example as brief as possible. Updated example again.

Comment: Do you call `ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init]; [viewController updateProgressBar:currentProgress]` in an another class?

Comment: No, and again, the problem is not that the method is not being called. it is, 100% being called.

Comment: I think the problem could be that two different instances of your ViewController are in operation here. I don't know your implementation yet- but can you confirm that one instance of viewController is already created when you want to change the progressBar progress from 0.5 to 1.0? Ideally, if the viewController is already created and EventsManager is trying to update the progressBar of the viewController based on some business logic, it could send the viewController a notification to update it's progress bar to a desired value that the EventsManager can provide.

Comment: Where do you initialize your `ViewController`? are you using storyboard? I agree with @Subzero about using different instances.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but the event manager is the only class that interacts with/creates an instance for this view. Not using a storyboard. The view controller is initialized and works just fine, I just can't manipulate it from outside classes. The only thing that works is calling `[self performSelectorOnMainThread...]` from within `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @masedesign, i have updated the solution. Please follow once

Comment: Thanks everyone, but there's clearly something I'm missing. I'm going to close this question and reinvestigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add an NSNotification for the progress bar update and call it from anywhere you want..

In your **viewDidLoad of ViewController** add this observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(progressBarUpdater:) name:@"progressBarUpdater" object:nil];
```

Then add the following method

```
-(void)progressBarUpdater:(float)currentProgress
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"progressBarUpdater" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:currentProgress,@"progress", nil]];
}
```

and Update your method

```
- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
{
    NSLog(@"updateProgressBar called.");
    NSDictionary *dict = [notificaiton userInfo];
    progressBar.progress = [dict valueForKey:@"progress"];

    //  progressBar.progress = myProgress;
}
```